# How to Understand C++11 random number generator

Tags: c++

Those three lines of generating random number looks a bit tricky. It is hard to always remember those lines. Could someone please shed some light on it to make it easier to understand?

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;  //1st line: Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine

    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //2nd line: Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);

    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)

        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';   //3rd line: Use dis to transform the random unsigned int generated by gen into an int in [1, 6]

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Here are some questions I can think of:

1. 1st line of code:
   `random_device` is a class as described by the documentation [random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device), so this line means declaring a object `rd`? If yes, why in 2nd line we pass `rd()` to construct mt19937 instead of using the object `rd` (without parentheses)?
2. 3rd line of code:
   Why do call class `uniform_int_distribution<>` object `dis()`? Is `dis()` a function? Why shall we pass in `gen` object into `dis()`?

Comment: The distribution maps a value returned by the engine to an integer between 1 and 6.

Comment: `random_device` is used to generate a very highly random (and potentially extremely expensive to generate so you don't just use `random_device` all the time) number used to seed the less expensive random number generator algorithms. The latter 2/3s of [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) cover just about all of this in good detail (and with jokes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

random_device is slow but genuinely random, it's used to generate the 'seed' for the random number sequence.

mt19937 is fast but only 'pseudo random'. It needs a 'seed' to start generating a sequence of numbers. That seed can be random (as in your example) so you get a different sequence of random numbers each time. But it could be a constant, so you get the same sequence of numbers each time.

uniform_int_distribution is a way of mapping random numbers (which could have any values) to the numbers you're actually interested in, in this case a uniform distribution of integers from 1 to 6.

As is often the case with OO programming, this code is about division of responsibilities. Each class contributes a small piece to the overall requirement (the generation of dice rolls). If you wanted to do something different it's easy because you've got all the pieces in front of you.

If this is too much then all you need to do is write a function to capture the overall effect, for instance

```
int dice_roll()
{
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);
    return dis(gen);
}
```

`dis` is an example of a *function object* or *functor*. It's an object which overloads `operator()` so it can be called as if it was a function.

Comment: Note to askers: In case you didn't notice, `random_device` is also a functor.

Comment: @coder It's pretty simple `class X { public: double operator()(int a, int b); };`. Now `X` is a functor, in this example it takes two `int` arguments and returns a `double`.

Comment: thanks, is mt19937 gen a functor as well? why don't we do `dis(gen())`?

Comment: @john Why dono't we do dis(gen()), since gen also have overloaded operator ()?

Comment: Well it's a design decision. It could have been designed the way you suggest. I'm guessing but I would say the actual design is a bit more flexible. if you look at the requirements for the [generator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UniformRandomBitGenerator) passed to `dis` you can see it's a bit more than just a functor. I imagine that `dis(G&)` also calls `G::min()` and `G::max()` to calculate the next number.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
    std::random_device rd;  // create access to truly random numbers

    std::mt19937 gen{rd()}; // create pseudo random generator. 
    // initialize its seed to truly random number.

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis{1, 6}; // define distribution 

    ...
    auto x = dis(gen); // generate pseudo random number form `gen`
    // and transform its result to desired distribution `dis`.
```